# How to create a taskbar application similar to Touch Keyboard on Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, taskbar

On Windows 8.1, if you right-click on the taskbar and point to Toolbars you can turn on Touch Keyboard, which makes a small image of a keyboard appear at the far right of the task bar just to the left of the notification area.

I want to develop an application that can make a presence here with a dynamically updating display of a time string (a count down application).

Can anyone advise if this is possible using C# .NET?

From various research I've discovered it is extremely difficult to determine exactly what Microsoft refer to this utility as. I have seen 'deskbar', 'deskband' and obviously it's under 'toolbars' in the task bar context menu. It also seems every major OS release changes the terminology and functionality completely. So bonus points if anyone can clear up what it's called on Windows 8.1 in addition to what term to research or MSDN article to read about developing an application that sits there.